# GitLab CI ..gitlab-ci.yml property to use fors static page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, gitlab, bundle, gitlab-ci, gitlab-pages

I am using GitLab to host my static page!
every time I am configuring the .gitlab-ci.yml file I am getting the following error: "Could not locate Gemfile"

Here is the output of the cmd
[image]

Here id the .gitlab-ci.yml file

```
image: ruby:2.3


before_script:
- bundle install

job:
  script:
  - gem install jekyll
  - jekyll build

pages:
  stage: deploy
  script:
  - bundle install
  - bundle exec jekyll build -d public
  artifacts:
    paths:
    - public
  only:
  - master

test:
  stage: test
  script:
  - bundle install
  - bundle exec jekyll build -d test
  artifacts:
    paths:
    - test
  except:
  - master
```

Comment: You need to pass the build as an artifact.

Comment: @JakubKania How this could be done?

Answer (score 2):

In your configuration I see a mixed of different install instructions:

- `bundle install` (in the before_script)
- `bundle install` (again, in the pages deploy script)
- `gem install jekyll`

The `Gemfile` is required by the `bundle` command, and it should specify mainly the dependency on jekyll (so again a duplication)

**PROPOSED SOLUTION**:
I suggest you to try with the configuration in the [gitlab pages sample](https://gitlab.com/pages/jekyll):

- gitlab-ci.yml

  ```
  image: ruby:2.3

  variables:
    JEKYLL_ENV: production

  before_script:
    - bundle install

  test:
    stage: test
    script:
    - bundle exec jekyll build -d test
    artifacts:
      paths:
      - test
    except:
    - master

  pages:
    stage: deploy
    script:
    - bundle exec jekyll build -d public
    artifacts:
      paths:
      - public
    only:
    - master
  ```
- Gemfile

  ```
  source "https://rubygems.org"
  ruby RUBY_VERSION

  # This will help ensure the proper Jekyll version is running.
  gem "jekyll", "3.4.0"

  # Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
  gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
  ```